# Javascript and [bind] implementation?

Tags: javascript

I read a bit about the bind implementation in JS ( from John Resig's book ) :

It looks something like this :  ( [**jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/osanun/2/edit))

```
#1Function.prototype.bind = function ()
#2{
#3    var fn = this,           
#4            args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
#5            object = args.shift();
#6
#7        return function ()
#8        {                    
#9            return fn.apply(object, args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));  
#10       };
#11   };
```

And I can test it like this:

```
var myObject = {};

function myFunction()
{
    return this == myObject;
}


//--------- 
if (!myFunction()) alert("Context is not set yet"); //not set ye

var bindedFunction= myFunction.bind(myObject)

if (bindedFunction()) alert( "Context is set properly"); //set properly
//---------
```

However I have 2 question  about the it :

<kbd>Question #1</kbd>

In Line #3  , the `this` is referes to the function which is executed  ,  correct ? but isn't `this` suppose to be : "the **object** which holds the function" ?

If I do `alert(this)` inside the bind function  , I see this :

```
function myFunction()
{
    return this == myObject;
}
```

<kbd>Question #2</kbd>

In line #9 , Why does the *returned* function is

```
  return function ()
        {                      
            return fn.apply ...
        };
```

and **not**

```
  return function ()
        {                      
           fn.apply ...
        };
```

I dont understand it :

the returned function creates a closure and should return a function which is only executing  `fn.apply(o....`

I don't understand why it returns additional `return` : like in `return  fn.apply(o....`

Comment: Q2: because some bound functions may return something and you want to get it after you call it. So that `return` returns what `myFunction` returns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context (no pun intended) of `Function.bind`, `this` does indeed refer to the currently invoked function, not the "object" that might contain it as a method.

Remembering that functions are first class objects in JS, when you write

```
myFunction.bind()
```

then `myFunction` *is* the object and `.bind` is then a method of that object (inherited via `Function.prototype`), and then when you invoke it the normal rules apply - `this === myFunction`.

For q.2, the *result* of `fn.apply` is required so that the bound function can also return a result, just as the original function might have.

Comment: what about the question _but isn't this suppose to be : "the object which holds the function" ?_

Comment: @RoyiNamir it's still true.  The object that contains the `bind` method _is_ the function, because it's part of `Function.prototype`.

Comment: @RoyiNamir yes, because functions are first-class objects in JS.

Comment: Everything is an object in JavaScript. `"hello".toLowerCase()`, `5.4.isNaN()`, `(true).valueOf()` and so on.

Comment: @Alnitak so why this is working without the return http://jsbin.com/osanun/3/edit ?

Comment: because you're ignoring the (non-existent) return value of `t()`.

Comment: `.bind()` is a function that _returns_ a function, that wraps the original function.  That returned (inner) function must behave the same way as the original, i.e. it must `return` the result of calling the original function.

Comment: I saw a simplier example . and this also works without return http://jsbin.com/ukotaq/2/edit

Comment: @Alnitak can you please go to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28024/room-for-royi-namir-and-alnitak

Comment: @Royi in that jsbin you're using the bind functionality for a click handler, so you would notice that returning false from your function will NOT stop event propagation unless the bound function proxies the return value.

Answer (score 1):

> but isn't this suppose to be : "the object which holds the function" ?

No. This is because internally `fn.bind(obj)` is invoked like this:

```
Function.bind.call(fn, window, obj)
```

Therefore, `this` refers to `fn`.

> I don't understand why it returns additional return : like in return fn.apply(o....

The function `.bind()` is meant to return a function that, when invoked, "proxies" the return value from your given function, i.e. `myFunction`. If not, it would always return `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to #2 is that the bound function should return whatever the original function returns, so it needs a return statement.